# Can't change position of 'Select' element (ASP.net)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

I try to use Bootstrap Dual Listbox , from here: http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/)
My problem is that the dual-list box always align to left, and I can't change it,
I try to write style attribute into the 'select' element, and try to link to css file, but nothing work.
This is the code:

```
<body>

       <select  id="sele" multiple="multiple" size="5" name="listbox" class='demo2 col-md-3' style="text-align:center">

        <% for(int i = 0 ; i <50; i++){  %>
        <option value="<%=i %>" ><%=i %></option>
        <%  } %>

    </select>



    <script>
        var demo2 = $('.demo2').bootstrapDualListbox({
            nonselectedlistlabel: 'Select',
            selectedlistlabel: 'Selected',
            preserveselectiononmove: 'moved',
            moveonselect: false,
            initialfilterfrom: ''
        });
    </script>
    <script src="libraries/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('input').placeholder();
        prettyPrint();
    </script>
</body>
```

this is how it look :
http://oi57.tinypic.com/262up7r.jpg
(instead in the center)
How can I fix that?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a container and then setting it to align center, like so:

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
    <select id="sele" multiple="multiple" size="5" name="listbox" class='demo2 col-md-3'>
        ...
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `<Select>` in a container div and set the following styles to the container div:

```
display: table; 
margin: 0 auto;
```

It should look something like this now

```
<div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto;">

    <select id="sele" multiple="multiple" size="5" name="listbox" class='demo2 col-md-3'>
        <!-- your stuff -->
    </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi,
the element move right, but still not to the center, and in addition the lists width change..(I try change the width back..but not help)
look like that:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/2dshkjd.jpg
maybe do you have another solution?

thanks!!